# Input_iterator, find_if and modulus

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator

I implemented an iterator, which has Fibonacci numbers as output. In my main() I'd like to find a number which is dividable by 17 (it's 34). Why doesn't work my find_if statement.

Thank you!

```
  #include <boost/operators.hpp>
  #include <algorithm>
  #include <tr1/functional>

    struct FibIter: boost::input_iterator_helper<FibIter,unsigned long long> {

 //typedef value_type unsigned long long;
 FibIter(value_type l=0):counter(0), fib0(0),fib1(1){
  while(l!=counter)
   ++(*this);
 }

 value_type operator*() const {return fib0;}
 FibIter& operator++() {
  ++counter; 
  value_type fnew = fib0+fib1;
  fib0 = fib1;
  fib1 = fnew;
  return *this;
  }
 bool operator==(FibIter const &other)const {
  return counter == other.counter;
 }


    private:
 value_type counter;
 value_type fib0, fib1;
    };

    using namespace std;
    using namespace tr1;
    using namespace placeholders;

    int main() {
 FibIter found = find_if(FibIter(), FibIter(100),bind(not2(modulus<unsigned long long>()),_1,17ULL));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it by using !boost::bind(...) instead of tr1::bind.

Answer (score 0):

```
bind(not2(modulus<unsigned long long>()),_1,17ULL)
```

should be

```
not1(bind(modulus<unsigned long long>(),_1,17ULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you start from first number which is 0, find will return it (**modulus(0,17) = 0**).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use `std::advance(*this,l);` instead of that `while` loop in your constructor. But! Your approach is **highly inefficient**, because it needs to compute the Fibonacci sequence *twice*: one to know what's the last Fibonacci number, and the second to actually get there when `++` is used by the client code.

I think better approach would be to store the index of the `last` Fibonacci number from the constructor in a private member and compare the counter with it after each `++`. It could be reused from the `index` field already present there, by making it this way:

Let a default constructor initialize the Fibonacci iterator to `fib0 = 0` and `fib1 = 1`, and `index = 0`. The other constructor (parametric) will be to create a dummy iterator which holds only the last index for the sequence, and other fields are invalid. This one iterator will be the "one-past-the-end" iterator, only for index comparisons, not for reading values.

So here's my solution:

```
#include <iterator>

class Fibonacci : public iterator<input_iterator_tag, int>
{
    unsigned index;
    value_type fib0, fib1;
 public:
    Fibonacci(): index(0), fib0(0), fib1(1) { }
    explicit Fibonacci(unsigned last): index(last), fib0(0), fib1(0) { }
    bool operator == (const Fibonacci& other) { return index == other.index; }
    bool operator != (const Fibonacci& other) { return !(*this == other); }
    value_type operator * () const { return fib0; }
    Fibonacci& operator ++ () {
        ++index;
        value_type fnew = fib0 + fib1;
        fib0 = fib1; fib1 = fnew;
        return *this;
    }
    Fibonacci operator ++ (int) {
        Fibonacci current(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return current;
    }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    ostream_iterator<int> out(cout, "; ");
    cout << "Fibonacci numbers from 0th to 19th:\n";
    copy(Fibonacci(), Fibonacci(20), out);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Fibonacci numbers from 0th to 19th:
0; 1; 1; 2; 3; 5; 8; 13; 21; 34; 55; 89; 144; 233; 377; 610; 987; 1597; 2584; 4181;
```

As you can see, there's also more code reuse in my example: I reuse operators inside other operators by calling them.

Of course it works only for numbers fitting into `int`. It'd be better to rewrite it to use multiple precision numbers (eg. GMP library).